# Is there a simpler method to make a pandas.Series monotonic?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a fast method to make a pandas dataframe monotonic in x.

My current solution is the following:

```
def make_monotonic(df, cols=None):
    """make df monotonic"""
    if not cols:
        cols = df.columns

    mycol = "_maximum"

    dfm = df.copy()
    for col in cols:
        dfm[mycol] = np.maximum.accumulate(dfm[col])
        dfm.drop_duplicates([mycol], keep="first", inplace=True)
    del dfm[mycol]
    return dfm

n=21
np.random.seed(21)
x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,n)
dx = .5 * (np.random.random(n)-.5)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"x0":x, "x":x+dx, "y":np.sin(x)})
dfm = make_monotonic(df, cols=["x"])
```

[Make colum x monotonic in "x"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOQi5.png)
[Make colum x monotonic in "x"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOQi5.png)

I want to generate a Function y = f(x)

```
            x         x0               y
0   -0.676913   0.000000    0.000000e+00
1   -0.002176   0.314159    3.090170e-01
2   0.959768    0.628319    5.877853e-01
3   0.224902    0.942478    8.090170e-01
4   0.815521    1.256637    9.510565e-01
5   0.896956    1.570796    1.000000e+00
6   1.588363    1.884956    9.510565e-01
7   2.444980    2.199115    8.090170e-01
8   2.225446    2.513274    5.877853e-01
9   2.952820    2.827433    3.090170e-01
10  2.495949    3.141593    1.224647e-16
```

to

```
            x         x0           y
0   -0.676913   0.000000    0.000000
1   -0.002176   0.314159    0.309017
2   0.959768    0.628319    0.587785
6   1.588363    1.884956    0.951057
7   2.444980    2.199115    0.809017
9   2.952820    2.827433    0.309017
```

Comment: what does even mean for a series to be monotonic in words?

Comment: "monotonic in x" means that the x value in each row should always be greater than the x value in the row before.

Comment: so you mean just sorting the data?

Comment: no, the dataframe is already sorted (index!). I will skip the rows which destroy the monotony.  I need only ascending `x` values, e.g. to use the column in `np.interp`.

Answer (score 13):

Theres actually a very simple way to do this with `df.cummax()`.

```
cols = ['your', 'columns']
mon_inc = (df[cols].cummax().diff().fillna(.1) > 0).all(axis=1)
df[mon_inc]
```

Older logic below:

You could keep taking the difference in rows using the `diff` method until all values are greater than 0.

```
while True:
    mon_inc = df['x'].diff().fillna(0) >= 0
    if mon_inc.all():
        break
    df = df[mon_inc]
```

And a function to do any number of columns

```
def make_monotonic(df, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = df.columns

    df1 = df.copy()[cols]

    while True:
        mon_inc = (df1.diff().fillna(0) >= 0).all(axis=1)
        if mon_inc.all():
            break
        df1 = df1[mon_inc]
    return df1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The solution looks good. The number of loops are not big for my usecases.

Comment: Wow! Amazing ;-) 
(to myself: RTFM ...) Unfortunately I can not vote for you due to a lack of scores, but I come back later ;-)

Comment: Fantastic.  For one column, not necessarily numeric, it reduces to df[df.col == df.col.cummax()].